# About iOS inhouse provisioning profile expiring

Tags: ios, profile, provisioning

A year ago I distributed an inhouse iOS app.And now,the provisioning profile is expired but not the associated certificate.Can I just renew the provisioning profile in the developer portal and let the user install the new profile using iPhone Configuration Utility or I have to re-sign the whole app using Xcode? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just renew the your provisioning profile.
If you want reinstall the app in your iOS device after expire the provisioning profile, you can't install. You need to make separate build with renewed fresh downloaded profile.

If app is already installed in devices then don't need to be worry. it will work.